# Deleting document and list libraries

Tags: sharepoint, delete-file, wss

Running WSS 3.0 and I've been given full access to sharepoint. I'm working on a lean initiative to clean up SP and delete old/outdated libraries from the site or at least from the main page. I've been able to get into quicklaunch where it gives me the option to remove it from quicklaunch but it's still showing on the front page. I've also found the button that lets me delete the document library but all it does is delete all the content. The link is still on the front page but when you click on it says something about the link being broken.

I'm on my own with this project and I'm not part of the IT team but I need to be able to delete document libraries and the content. Or at least edit the front page to remove these links.

I've found a lot on the internet about powershell and sharepoint designer but I don't have either of those and I'm not sure if I'd be tech savvy enough to use them. Please tell me there is some secret button I can hit to remove the useless libraries.